# Multiply a scalar to a tensor with tensorflow keras backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm going to use a sawtooth activation function in one layer and have defined it like this: 
(the form of sawtooth function is not the important part and it is this function of x for a sum over many terms: 
 `sin(x) - 1⁄2sin(2x) + 1⁄3sin(3x) - 1⁄4sin(4x) + 1⁄5sin(5x) - 1⁄6sin(6x) + ...` , I've used 500 terms).

```
def sawtooth1 (x):
    I= K.arange (1, 500, dtype='float32')
    out= K.sum(-K.sin(K.dot(I,(x+pi)))/I, axis= 1)
    return out[0]
```

this works well with numpy. but when i'm using this function with input shape here:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
saw = Dense(1, activation= sawtooth1)(inputs)
```

I get this error about shape of matmul inputs:
`ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'dense_1/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [499], [?,1].`

I've tried too many ways to handle this but any of them didn't work.
how to do the matmul with Keras backend?

Comment: Hi Farzin, welcome to SO!. After this line, `I= K.arange (1, 500, dtype='float32')`, add `I = I[:, None]`.

Comment: Thank you @learner. This works properly. By the way, I've changed the form of initializations of the list I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

After adding `I = I[:, None]` to `sawtooth1` function has resolved the issue.

Here is the updated code

```
def sawtooth1 (x):
    I= K.arange (1, 500, dtype='float32')
    I = I[:, None]
    out= K.sum(-K.sin(K.dot(I,(x+np.pi)))/I, axis= 1)
    return out[0]

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
saw = Dense(1, activation= sawtooth1)(inputs)
```